# How do I pass variable to background-image property of css?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

```
@if (!(Model.IsPublished == false && Model.IsArchieved == false))
    {
        var watermarkImage = "../../Resources/Watermark/" + Model.Watermark + ".png";

        <style type="text/css">
            .watermark {
                background-image: url("../../Resources/Watermark/Draft5.png");
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100000;
            }
        </style>
    }
```

I want to pass watermarkImage in 
`background-image: url(@watermarkImage);`
But this is not working.
How can I pass this variable value to css background-image property?

Comment: @Url.content is also not working here.

Comment: `this is not working` - Tell us why you think so. What you see and what you  expect instead of not working.

Comment: I've never tried this approach before, but I just tested this and it does work....you must have something else wrong that is causing your "issue".  Along with Mat J's comment, we'd need to see what HTML element you are targeting with this to be able to help.

Comment: I am using Rotativa to convert Cshtml to Pdf, in that cshtml I used purely html table based structure  and in my Index.cshtml @Url tage is not accessible. Let me know if there is a way

Comment: When I use background-image: url(@watermarkImage); syntax, all rest of css properties vulnerabled

Comment: I need a correct syntax to pass a Model Data into the background-image url

Comment: I have never used Rotativa so I can't speak to its usage or implementation.  To test the theory of mixing Razor and your styling, I just added a simple HTML img tag with class=watermark and used the same syntax you had for url(@watermarkImage).  I'm not sure what you mean by "all rest of css properties vulnerabled" though, but in HTML this syntax is working as you would expect it to.

Comment: "all rest of css properties vulnerabled"  means : asp.net has color combination to identify tags and all. so when i used that syntax rest of the css styles gets black colored. meaning that not accessible

Comment: The rest of the CSS properties are not colored properly in VS in my test either, but they are still being applied properly.   Have you tried to test your code is a simpler example (ie...without Rotativa and the PDF part)?  I will add an answer with my test so you can see what I did to test, which does work in terms of the actual watermark styling and your injected image.  If that doesn't help, you need to do some additional troubleshooting on your end and give more details of what is actually wrong.

Comment: did you try to use "@Url.Content("~/Resources/Watermark/" + Model.Watermark + ".png")"

Comment: yes, its shows me "Url does not exists in the current context"